# How to create an application under my default stage instead of stage "undefined"

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

I'm creating a custom module to fix a default stage and it became automatically created but always when i create a new application it will be created under undefined stage and i want it to be created under my default stage . Any idea how to fix this problem please? here is my code

**hr_recruitment_view.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <odoo>
  <data noupdate="1">
    <record model="hr.recruitment.stage" id="default_stage_job">
        <field name="name">CV in progress</field>
        <field name="sequence">0</field>

    </record>
</data>
</odoo>
```

**hr_recruitment.py**

```py
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from odoo import fields, api, models

    class Applicant(models.Model):
    _inherit = "hr.applicant"

    def _default_stage_id(self):
        # Search your stage
        stage_id = self.env['hr.recruitment.stage'].search([('name', '=', 'CV in progress')], limit=1).id
        if stage_id:
            return stage_id
        return super(Applicant, self)._default_stage_id()
```

[image]

Comment: Are you depending from `hr_recruitment` addon? Have you debugged so you can narrow the issue? I mean, is your method override executing at all? Or is it that the method is not finding the record? By the way, you should not assume the name of the record is never going to change. Don't use it to search. Instead, get your record using the external identifier: `stage_id = self.env.ref('<addon_name>.default_stage_job').id`

Comment: Yes i'm depending from hr_recruitement

Comment: What about my other questions?

Comment: I could not debug my code because i m working on server

Comment: @Dhouda You can use Pdb and odoo shell to debug your code on a production server.